# AudioToolBox worked fine, but now makes audio sound really quiet

Tags: xcode, swift

I just wrote this code. You press a button and hear a sound. I imported AudioToolBox. It worked fine the first 10 times I opened and used my app, but now for some reason it sounds like my audio is very quiet, even though the volume on my phone is all the way up and the audio that is produced by AVFoundation sounds fine.

Anyone know how this would be possible?

```
import AVFoundation
import AudioToolBox

@IBAction func buttonOne(sender: UIButton) {

    var soundID: SystemSoundID = 0
    let soundURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), "C-note", "mp3", nil)
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &soundID)
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)

    let wSize : CGFloat = 20
    let hSize : CGFloat = 35

    let yPosition : CGFloat = 40

    let dot = UIImageView()
    dot.image = UIImage(named: "drop")
    dot.frame = CGRect(x: 33, y: yPosition, width: wSize, height: hSize)
    self.view.addSubview(dot)

    let duration = 0.7
    let delay = 0.0
    let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: options, animations: {
        dot.frame = CGRect(x: 33, y: 360, width: wSize, height: hSize)
        }, completion: { animationFinished in
            dot.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}
```

Comment: You are aware that `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` is a totally crappy way to play sound, right?

Comment: No. I have only worked with this way so far, what other way is there? I heard that AudioToolBox is a great way to play sound, I have never worked with this framework so I don't know it that well, so if you have any other idea on how to play sound I'd be happy to hear it. I chose AudioToolBox because there is little latency. At this point the sound isn't working at all anymore and my other buttons that aren't connected to AudioToolBox aren't responding properly anymore.

Comment: It's for simple beep sounds, and you're not doing it right in any case (you have memory management responsibilities that you are failing to perform - and you cannot perform in Swift in any case). I would suggest using AVAudioPlayer (or maybe AVAudioEngine if you want to get a little lower-level).

Comment: I have used AVAudioPlayer in AVFoundation and I am encountering latency issues there. I was recommend AudioToolbox and it was working. I can see I'm doing something wrong. I'm trying to create a piano-like app, therefor it's important to have no latency issues. I will look up how AVAudioEngine works.. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Would you recommend using OpenAL?

Comment: Try AVAudioEngine first, because it is an easy front end for OpenAL.